# Can you read in your dreams?

Tags: dreams

I had a dream this morning. In my dream, I was using my laptop and I read a fan fiction in the internet. I have never read that fan fiction before (on principle I don't read fan fiction of that particular franchise). Furthermore, the writing style was very unlike me (I would vehemently deny it if such style was attributed to me). Also, the story if that fan fiction is not my particular head canon (if I did decide to write fan fiction, it wouldn't be that particular story).

Also, there were comments on the fan fiction which seemed very organic (the comments espoused a wide variety of opinions on the fan fiction), and contributed to the authenticity.

I did not bother searching for the story of the fan fiction to see if it actually exists, because I felt it was a pointless venture; I haven't read any fan fiction of that particular franchise.

I have read that you cannot read in dreams, and that contradicts my experience.

- Can you read in dreams?
- Why?
- An explanation for my particular dream?

Comment: I have also heard that you can't read in dreams, yet I've also had such experiences where I read and I somehow even remember the general font and writing style. Perhaps while dream-reading you are staring at a bunch of letter like things without any real meaning, making their meaning in your head. Your thoughts direct your dreams, perhaps. So in the same way, you may be "guessing" what is written in your dream, making it up on the go, and fooling yourself into thinking you're indeed reading.